# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu (n)}{n^{s}}=\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$?

Tags: riemann-zeta

How can we prove this equation? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu (n)}{n^{s}}=\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with [Mobius inversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusInversionFormula.html)? If you are, then try multiplying the series for $\zeta(s)$ by $\sum \mu(n)/n^s$ and expanding.

Comment: Or find Euler product formula for that Dirichlet series.

Comment: @CardboardBox I know it's been 6 years but hopefully you're still active haha. How can we apply Mobius inversion here since the sum is from 1 to infinity and not over the divisors of n? I'm trying to prove this without the Euler product formula.

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar If you multiply two Dirichlet series $\sum a_n n^{-s}$ and $\sum b_n n^{-s}$, note that the result is $\sum c_n n^{-s}$, where $c_n = \sum_{d \mid n} a_d b_{n/d}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a(n)$ be a multiplicative number-theoretic function function. Then we have
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \{1 + a(p)p^{-s} + a(p^2)p^{-2s} + \cdots\}, \quad \operatorname{Re}[s] \geq s_0,$$
which is known as the Euler product formula. The equality above is not difficult to verify.
Suppose $a(n) = \mu(n)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} &= \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \{1 + \mu(p)p^{-s} + \mu(p^2)p^{-2s} + \cdots\}\\
&= \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \{1 - p^{-s}\},
\end{align*}
for it is obvious that $\mu(p) = -1$ and $\mu(p^s) = 0$ for $s = 2, 3, 4, \ldots$ whenever $p$ is prime. But
$$\prod_{p \text{ prime}} \{1 - p^{-s}\} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)},$$
so we are done.