# proof with Euler products

Tags: number-theory

Let $\zeta(s)$ be the Riemann zeta function.$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}.$$
 Then we know it satisfies the Euler product for $\text{Re}(s) > 1$,

$$\zeta(s) = \prod_{p} (1 - p^{-s})^{-1}.$$
I need to use Euler products to proof that

$$\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}  = \prod_{p} (1 + p^{-s})^{-1}.
$$

I know that $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{μ(n)}{n^s} 
$$
(μ is mobius function)

I am really don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Use the Euler product given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745744/how-to-prove-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mu-nns-frac1-zeta-s).

Comment: $Is 1-p^{-2s}=(1-p^{-s})(1+p^{-s})$?

Comment: thank you very much. it's so simple that it's genius

Comment: qqqaaa Would be good if you use @N.Quy hint to write a (two lines) answer.